# Issue with as_hex() function in perl

Tags: regex, perl, bigint

I am trying to write a code to CIDR for IPv6.

Basicall, I am getting the CIDR perfix in my code and convert it to the binary.

Then using as_hex() function in BigInt library, I convert it into the hexadecimal.

That works fine.

The problem is when I try to get the hexadecimal for inverted binary. some how I cant get it, it prints out white spaces.

Prefix : 78

Actual Binary:
0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Hex: 
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc:0000:0000:0000

Inverted Binary:
0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Hex:
3fff:ffff:ffff:f::::

Any ideas????

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using here so people can try and reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to handle the leading zeros, which as_hex seems to get rid of by default.  Using the two binary sequences you provided:

```
use Math::BigInt;

sub paddedHex {
  my ($binary) = @_;
  my $x = substr(Math::BigInt->new($binary)->as_hex(), 2, -1);
  return sprintf("0x%032s\n", $x);
}

my @binaries = qw/
0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
/;

for my $binary (@binaries) {
  print paddedHex($binary), "\n";
}
```

I got this output:

```
0x0fffffffffffffffffffc00000000000

0x000000000000000000003fffffffffff
```

Hopefully this helps?